# Переполнение в PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

print json_encode($data);
```

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28 bytes) .

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Вам прям так нужны абсолютно все данные из таблицы table

Comment: @Naumov просто интересно) Когда я юзал методы mysql , то выдавались полностью значения, а тут вот так)

Comment: Вы вытаскиваете всю таблицу в память, память грохается

Comment: Попробуйте `var_dump($data)` для начала может у вас fetchAll с ошибкой выполняеться и где `execute`  к стати.

Comment: @Naumov, всмысле с ошибкой)Все работает же)

Comment: @MartinezToni Да вижу што работает. Просто при ошибке в php функции могут уходить в рекурсию и есть память. Так же при выводе не лимитированных данных на страницу, тоже потребляеться память так как формируеться буффер вывода.

Comment: @MartinezToni, лучше прочитайте про параметры fetchAll http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php В том виде в котором вы ее используете, у вас возвращается массив как с индексированными номерами столбцов, так и индексированными именами!

Comment: @Naumov

Почему у меня не сравнивается?

Comment: @Naumov  $token = $_GET["token"];

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT token FROM Tokens WHERE token =? LIMIT 1")->execute(array($token));

if($stmt != null ){

Comment: @Visman поможете?

Comment: Вы можете использовать `fetchAll(FETCH_ASSOC)` для получения ассоциативного массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В начале скрипта

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2G');
```

но я бы подумал о том что бы переработать алгоритм web-скрипту слишком много.

Если постраницная загрузка то вам нужно столько элементов получить сколько есть на странице. Это плохой вариант для web скриптов. Потому как память не резиновая и резервировать столько памяти это плохо для исполнения скрипта. Ибо она не будет доступна для других приложений и 5-6(одновременных) запусков скрипта просто повалят ваш сервер... Такой вариант не подойдёт для более менее загруженого проэкта

Comment: помогли)Спасибо)

На начальном этапе нужно получить фул)

В дальнейшем, у меня на клиенте будет постраничная загрузка, и как я понимаю тут, нужно будет изменить структуру запроса)

Comment: т.е. Если постраницная загрузка то вам нужно столько элементов получить сколько есть на странице. Это плохой вариант для web скриптов. Потому как память не резиновая и резервировать столько памяти это плохо для исполнения скрипта. Ибо она не будет доступна для других приложений и 5-6(одновременных) запусков скрипта просто повалят ваш сервер... Такой вариант не подойдёт для более менее загруженого проэкта

Comment: Если помог то отметьте ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 5):

> Как решить данную проблему?

**Не делать** запросов вида `SELECT * FROM table`, а всегда запрашивать только те данные, которые нужны для отображения на странице.

И тем более не применять чудовищные костыли из другого ответа.

Comment: Вы наверное никогда не дочитываете ответы до конца. Плюс ваш ответ не являеться ответом на вопрос.

Comment: @Naumov утечка памяти вполне может быть связана с запросом, который возвращает всю таблицу. Таблицы большие бывают. А вы вместо оптимизации предлагаете просто дать больше памяти. Это как-то недальновидно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я и написал в своём ответе что это плохая идея давать web скрипту больше памяти. О чём говорит мой коментарий `
т.е. Если постраницная загрузка то вам нужно столько элементов получить сколько есть на странице. Это плохой вариант для web скриптов. Потому как память не резиновая и резервировать столько памяти это плохо для исполнения скрипта. Ибо она не будет доступна для других приложений и 5-6(одновременных) запусков скрипта просто повалят ваш сервер... Такой вариант не подойдёт для более менее загруженого проэкта ` и последние строки ответа .

Comment: @NickVolynkin А если вы считает что вполне для СО, в полне нормально отвечать, на то што человек предложил конкретное решение конкретного вопроса и предупредил при этом человека о не подводных комнях такого ответа, что `И тем более не применять чудовищные костыли из другого ответа. ` и при том ответ не содержит ни каких конкретных предложений, я не буду спорить с вами. Я просто в своих коментариях к ответам буду ссылаться на ваш коментарий в этой теме и говорить людям, `что они пишут кастыли, и быдлокодеры`, что бы меня не забанили за это. В общем, будет ответ полный расписанный и т.д.

Comment: @NickVolynkin А пока это реплика коментарий и не более того...

Comment: @Naumov "костыли" - это характеристика решения, а не человека. Совсем не то же, что "быдлокодер".

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я вас понял, и думаю обсуждать данный ответ дальше не имеет смысла, так как я не смогу вам доказать что этот ответ как минимум оскарбителен и явлеться не более чем коментарием. А вы мне не докажите что этот ответ имеет место быть.